# How to use without derivative prove $-(b+|2a-b|)\le 4ax^3-2bx\le 2a-b+|2a-b|$

Tags: inequality

Let $a>0$,and $b\in R$, show that
$$-(b+|2a-b|)\le  4ax^3-2bx\le 2a-b+|2a-b|,\forall x\in [0,1]$$
can you without derivative solve it? such $AM-GM$,Cauchy-schwarz inequality and so on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Gives the expression of $-(b+|2a-b|)$ and $2a-b+|2a-b|$ when $2a<b$ and $2a\geq b$. Then use the fact

$$4ax^3-2bx=x(4ax^2-2b)$$

and conclude.

**Added :**

I do (a small part of) the case $2a\geq b$ to give you an example. If $2a\geq b$, then $$-(b+|2a-b|)=-2a\leq 0$$
since $a>0$. 
$$2a-b+|2a-b|=2a-b+2a-b=4a-2b.$$

Let $x\in[0,1]$. Notice that if $b<0$, then $4ax^2-2b>0$. If $ 0\leq b\leq \sqrt{2a}$, then $$4ax^2-2b<0,\quad\text{if }x\in\left[0,\frac{b}{\sqrt {2a}}\right[$$ and $$4ax^2-2b\geq 0,\quad\text{if } x\in\left[\frac{b}{\sqrt {2a}},1\right].$$

Finally, if $b>\sqrt{2a}$, then

$$4ax^2-2b<0.$$

Therefore, if $0\leq b\leq \sqrt{2a}$, and $x\in\left[0,\frac{b}{\sqrt{2a}}\right]$,

$$-2a\leq 0\leq x(4ax^2-2b)\leq 4ax^2-2b\leq 4a-2b$$
But now you have to do it for all cases to conclude for $2a>b$ and do the same for $2a<b$.

Good luck :-)

Comment: can  you  without derivative to solve it?

Comment: I don't use derivative !! There are just simple comparaisons to do ! What's the problem ?

Comment: How to explain where point is maximun or minumin?